# Es como conveniente usar LAST_INSERT_ID para obtener el ID del último INSERT en un server MySQL muy concurrido?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una pregunta, estoy desarrollando una página web desde la cual se van a insertar datos en una base de datos MySQL, el objetivo es que inmediatamente después de insertar un registro me retorne el ID con el que se insertó dicho registro, la problemática es que por ser una base en la que se van a estar insertando continuamente registros es posible entre que haga el INSERT y el SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID vaya a haber otro usuario que ingrese un registro y me devuelva el ID del otro usuario y no el mío? Aclaro que el LAST_INSERT_ID lo hago inmediatamente después del INSERT, pero me ocasiona la duda si hay alguna posibilidad que suceda eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenos días, no vas a tener ningún problema como lo estas haciendo porque en la teoría cuando tu haces un **INSERT** estas abriendo un cursor a la base de datos y ese cursor tiene como una especie de **ID** o un **RESOURCE ID** interno el cual es manejado hasta que se cierre dicho cursor, en tu caso después de usar el LAST_INSERT_ID, te recomiendo para blindar ese comportamiento usar un **Procedimiento Almacenado** donde hagas el **INSERT** y uses como parámetro de salida el ultimo **ID** registrado, ó si no quieres usar un **Procedimiento Almacenado** puedes indicarle antes de hacer el **insert** que vas hacer una transacción colocando algo como:

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
```

y luego colocas el **insert** y el LAST_INSERT_ID. Despues del **LAST_INSERT_ID** cierras la transacción indicando:

```
$mysqli->commit(); ó $mysqli->rollback();

$mysqli->close();
```

Espero que te sirva y si no fui muy claro avísame para mejorar mi respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto. Tiene mucha lógica